# After adding .jar files in libs folder it showing error when trying to run

Tags: android

Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'.

> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

And if we remove .jar files from libs folder it will work with out any  error and warnings

gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
signingConfigs {
    config {

    }
}
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries true
    dexInProcess = true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    versionName "1.0.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
productFlavors {
}}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('com.alibaba.android:ultraviewpager:1.0.6.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.0.2'
compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
compile project(':milla')
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
// base library
//slider
compile 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.8.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:27.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.6'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.3'
compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please share your app gradle file.

Comment: ok  , i shared gradle file